# How to solve these warnings? | VHDL Programming

Tags: warnings, vhdl, fpga, xilinx

So I'm trying to implement a I2C master on a FPGA, and I get the following Errors. Does someone know how to solve them?
Thanks!

> WARNING:Xst:646 - Signal <thirdaddress> is assigned but never used. This unconnected signal will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>
> WARNING:Xst:646 - Signal <secondaddress> is assigned but never used. This unconnected signal will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>
> WARNING:Xst:646 - Signal <firstaddress> is assigned but never used. This unconnected signal will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>
> WARNING:Xst:736 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <Mtridata_sda> created at line 44. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
>
> WARNING:Xst:736 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <Mtrien_sda> created at line 44. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
>
> WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 3-bit latch for signal <sendcount>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
>
> WARNING:Xst:1293 - FF/Latch <XLXI_9/sendcount_2> has a constant value of 0 in block <top_level>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>
> WARNING:Xst:1293 - FF/Latch <XLXI_9/sendcount_1> has a constant value of 0 in block <top_level>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>
> WARNING:Xst:1293 - FF/Latch <XLXI_9/sendcount_0> has a constant value of 0 in block <top_level>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>
> WARNING:Xst:1896 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <XLXI_9/current_state_FSM_FFd1> has a constant value of 0 in block <top_level>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
>
> WARNING:Xst:1294 - Latch <XLXI_9/Mtridata_sda> is equivalent to a wire in block <top_level>.
>
> WARNING:Xst:1294 - Latch <XLXI_9/Mtrien_sda> is equivalent to a wire in block <top_level>.

Here is the code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity i2cmaster is
    Port ( sda : inout  STD_LOGIC;
           scl : out  STD_LOGIC;
           sclclk : in  STD_LOGIC;
           reset : in  STD_LOGIC;
           clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
           dataout : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
           resettodivider : out  STD_LOGIC);
end i2cmaster;

architecture Behavioral of i2cmaster is

type state_type is (startstate1, startstate2, sendaddress1, acknowlegde1,  sendinternaladdress, acknowlegde2, startstate3, startstate4, sendaddress2, acknowlegde3, readdata, notacknowlegde, stopstate );
signal current_state : state_type;
signal next_state : state_type :=startstate1;
signal firstaddress: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal secondaddress: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal thirdaddress: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal sendcount: integer range 0 to 7 := 0;
signal temp : std_logic := '0';
signal tempdata : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0):="00000000";

begin

firstaddress<="10101010"; -- Slaveaddress + Writebit
secondaddress<="10101010"; -- Internal Address(first)
thirdaddress<="10101010"; -- Slaveaddress + Readbit


process(current_state, sda, sclclk, temp, sendcount, firstaddress, secondaddress, thirdaddress)
begin
case current_state is

------------------------
    when startstate1 =>
        temp<='0';
        sendcount <=0;
        resettodivider <='1';
        sda<='1';
        next_state <= startstate2;
------------------------        
    when startstate2 =>
        temp<='0';
        sendcount <=0;
        resettodivider <='0';
        sda<='0';   
        if sclclk = '0' then
            next_state <= sendaddress1;
        else
            next_state <= startstate2;      
        end if;     
------------------------        
    when sendaddress1 =>
    resettodivider <='0';

        if sendcount <= 7 then

            if sclclk = '0' and temp='0' then
                sda<=firstaddress(sendcount);
                sendcount <= sendcount + 1;
                temp<='1';
                next_state<=sendaddress1;
            elsif sclclk='1' then
                temp<='0';
                sendcount <=sendcount;
                next_state<=sendaddress1;
            else
                temp<='0';
                sda<='Z';
                sendcount <= sendcount;
                next_state<=sendaddress1;           
            end if;

        else
            temp<='0';
            sendcount <= 0;
            next_state<=acknowlegde1;
        end if;
------------------------            

    when acknowlegde1 =>
    temp<='0';
    resettodivider <='0';
    sendcount <=0;
        if sclclk='1' then
            if sda ='1' then
            next_state<=startstate1;
            else
            next_state<=acknowlegde1;
            end if;
        else
            next_state<=sendinternaladdress;

        end if;
------------------------        
    when sendinternaladdress =>
    resettodivider <='0';
        if sendcount <= 7 then

            if sclclk = '0' and temp='0' then
                sda<=secondaddress(sendcount);
                sendcount<= sendcount + 1;
                temp<='1';
                next_state<=sendinternaladdress;
            elsif sclclk='1' then
                temp<='0';
                sendcount <=sendcount;
                next_state<=sendinternaladdress;
            else
                temp<='0';
                sendcount <= sendcount;
                next_state<=sendinternaladdress;    
                sda<='Z';               
            end if;

        else
            temp<='0';
            sendcount<= 0;
            next_state<=acknowlegde2;
        end if;
------------------------            

    when acknowlegde2 =>
    sendcount <=0;
    temp<='0';
    resettodivider <='0';
        if sclclk='1' then
            if sda ='1' then
            next_state<=startstate1;
            else
            next_state<=acknowlegde2;
            end if;
        else
            next_state<=startstate3;

        end if;
    ------------------------    
    when startstate3 =>
        sendcount <=0;
        temp<='0';
        resettodivider <='1';
        sda<='1';
        next_state <= startstate4;

    ------------------------
    when startstate4 =>
        temp<='0';
        resettodivider <='0';
        sda<='0';   
        sendcount <=0;
        if sclclk = '0' then
            next_state <= sendaddress2;
        else
            next_state <= startstate4;      
        end if;     
    ------------------------
    when sendaddress2 =>
    resettodivider <='0';
        if sendcount <= 7 then
            if sclclk = '0' and temp='0' then
                sda<=thirdaddress(sendcount);
                sendcount<= sendcount + 1;
                temp<='1';
                next_state<=sendaddress2;
            elsif sclclk='1' then
                sendcount<= sendcount;
                temp<='0';
                next_state<=sendaddress2;
            else
                sendcount<= sendcount;
                temp<='0';
                sda<='Z';
                next_state<=sendaddress2;           
            end if;

        else
            temp<='0';
            sendcount <=0;
            next_state<=acknowlegde3;
        end if;

    ------------------------
    when acknowlegde3 =>
    temp<='0';
    sendcount<=0;
    resettodivider <='0';
        if sclclk='1' then
            if sda ='1' then
            next_state<=startstate1;
            else
            next_state<=acknowlegde3;
            end if;
        else
            next_state<=readdata;

        end if;
    ------------------------
    when readdata =>
    resettodivider <='0';
            if sendcount <= 7 then
            if sclclk = '0' and temp='0' then

                tempdata(sendcount)<=sda;
                tempdata<=tempdata;
                sendcount<= sendcount + 1;
                temp<='1';
                next_state<=readdata;
            elsif sclclk='1' then
                tempdata(sendcount)<='0';
                temp<='0';
                sendcount <= sendcount;
                next_state<=readdata;
            else
                temp<='0';
                tempdata(sendcount)<='0';
                sendcount <= sendcount;
                next_state<=readdata;

            end if;

        else
            temp<='0';
            tempdata(sendcount)<='0';
            sendcount <= 0;
            next_state<=notacknowlegde;
        end if;

    ------------------------
    when notacknowlegde =>
    sendcount<=0;
    temp<='0';
    resettodivider <='0';
        if sclclk='0' then
            next_state<=stopstate;
            sda<='Z';
        else
            sda<='1';
            next_state<=notacknowlegde;
        end if;
    ------------------------
    when stopstate =>
        sendcount<=0;
        temp<='0';
        sda<='0';
        resettodivider <='1';
        next_state<=startstate1;

    ------------------------
    when others =>
    sendcount<=0;
    temp<='0';
    resettodivider <='0';
    next_state<=startstate1;
    sda<='Z';
    scl<='Z';
    end case;

end process;

-------

process(clk, reset)
begin
    if (reset='1') then

        current_state <= startstate1;
    elsif rising_edge(clk) then
        current_state <= next_state; 
    end if;
end process;

-------

scl<=sclclk;
dataout<= tempdata;


end Behavioral;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Complaining about dead/unused code**

```
WARNING:Xst:646
  Signal <thirdaddress> is assigned but never used.
  Signal <secondaddress> is assigned but never used.
  Signal <firstaddress> is assigned but never used.
```

This means these three signals are unused in your design. If you don't plan to use them in future, you can remove them -> dead code.

**Warning about latches -> bad design**

```
WARNING:Xst:736
  Found 1-bit latch for signal <Mtridata_sda> created at line 44.
  Found 1-bit latch for signal <Mtrien_sda> created at line 44.
  Found 3-bit latch for signal <sendcount>.

Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements.
We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as
they may lead to timing problems.
```

Your state transition process does not assign each output signal for every input combination. This can be solved by extending your others case or generally introducing default assignments before the case statement.

**Warning about registers, which don't change there value => constant content**

```
WARNING:Xst:1293
  FF/Latch <XLXI_9/sendcount_2> has a constant value of 0 in block <top_level>.
  FF/Latch <XLXI_9/sendcount_1> has a constant value of 0 in block <top_level>.
  FF/Latch <XLXI_9/sendcount_0> has a constant value of 0 in block <top_level>.

This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
```

Your counter sendcount gets removed. This fault is mostly caused if:
- a FSM hangs up and does not generate controls for a counter
- the counter is held in reset
- the counter does not get any increment/enable signal

**Warning of unreached states**

```
WARNING:Xst:1896
  Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <XLXI_9/current_state_FSM_FFd1> has
  a constant value of 0 in block <top_level>.

This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
```

This is a propagation message. Trimming registers, latches and logic on one end of the circuit can cause further "optimizations" / trimming on the other side.

An unreached state report can be found in the synthesis report. Search for 'unreached'.